# what is easiest way of working arrays in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsnumber

I want to create function to return a 1d array with 2 elements in it something like below :

```
(NSArray *) myFunction {
 NSArray * myArr = [[NSArray alloc]initwithobjects:[NSNumbers numberwithfloat:1.0f],[NSNumbers numberwithfloat:1.0f]];
//the above line is just pseudo code 

}
```

but when I want to retrieve nsarray form this function i want to do it at the simplest way
which it seems impossible in objective-c
this is what I've written to get two simple float value which is not appropariate but i don't have any further knowledge of how to doing it in simpler way

```
NSArray *tt2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self myFunction]];
 float fp1=0.0f;
    float fp2=0.0f;
    BOOL firstTime = YES;
    for(NSNumber *n in tt2)
    {
        if (firstTime) {
            NSLog(@"%@" , n);
            fp1 = [n floatValue];
            firstTime = NO;
        }
        else {
            fp2 = [n floatValue];
        }

    }
```

above code is ridiculos but i don't have any other choice unless you advice me how can I convert a nsarray to nsnumber then a nsnumber to float[]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're only storing floats, you could just use a C array instead. NSArray can only store objects.

However, it looks like you haven't heard of the `objectAtIndex` method?

```
NSNumber *firstNumber = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSNumber *secondNumber = [myArray objectAtIndex:1];
```

Does that help with your situation, it isn't really clear what you're trying to do from the question.

Comment: I've read somewhere that we can't return float[] from another function. thats why we have to create a lot of bloated code around.

Comment: That does seem to be the case, or at least it's not straightforward to do so - I didn't know that, thanks for the info! I think you could have the C array as an ivar though if you're not accessing it from other objects.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a C array.

```
// C function returning dynamically allocated array of floats.
float *CreateNumbers(void)
{
    float *numArray = malloc(sizeof(float));
    numArray[0] = 1.0;
    numArray[1] = 2.0;

    return numArray;
}


- (void)exampleMethod
{
    float *numbers = CreateNumbers();
    float val1 = numbers[0];
    float val2 = numbers[1];

    NSLog(@"val1: %.2f, val2: %.2f\n", val1, val2);

    free(numbers);
}
```